# How to go about already asked questions, whose answers are not valid/working anymore

Tags: support

I have come across an issue, which was exactly something someone else faced and there is a question, with answers which satisfied the OPs issue.
But now that answer is not working anymore, at-least not in my case.

How to go about such situations?

To give an example of the situation, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792826/the-dataflow-appears-to-be-stuck) is a question asked by a fellow Stackoverflow user, and by some magic his issue got solved and the accepted answer mentions what he did.
It did not work in my case. For time being, i added comments in the question asking for help.

What is the right way to handle such situations?

Comment: *Why* doesn't the solution work anymore? If the product has changed (*e.g.*, new version), then you should ask a new question. If it's just something different about your environment and you're looking for an alternate solution, then a bounty would be more appropriate.

Comment: You can re-ask the question, but clearly state that you've read that question, tried the solution, and it didn't work, else you probably will get marked as a duplicate (if the previous answer contained code, show your implementation, and any errors it produced).

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but since my previous questions had a bad reputation, I just wanted to make sure that i do what is right. Thank you!